# How to use a Batchsampler within a Dataloader

Tags: pytorch, dataloader

I have a need to use a `BatchSampler` within a pytorch `DataLoader` instead of calling `__getitem__` of the dataset multiple times (remote dataset, each query is pricy). 
I cannot understand how to use the batchsampler with **any** given dataset.

e.g

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, remote_ddf, ):
        self.ddf = remote_ddf

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.ddf)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.ddf[idx] --------> This is as expensive as a batch call

    def get_batch(self, batch_idx):
        return self.ddf[batch_idx]

my_loader = DataLoader(MyDataset(remote_ddf), 
           batch_sampler=BatchSampler(Sampler(), batch_size=3))
```

The thing I do not understand, neither found any example online or in torch docs, is how do I use my `get_batch` function instead of the __getitem__ function. 

Edit:
Following the answer of Szymon Maszke, this is what I tried and yet, `\_\_get_item__` gets one index each call, instead of a list of size `batch_size`

```
class Dataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self):
       ...

    def __len__(self):
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, batch_idx):  ------> here I get only one index
        return self.wiki_df.loc[batch_idx]


loader = DataLoader(
                dataset=dataset,
                batch_sampler=BatchSampler(
                    SequentialSampler(dataset), batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size, drop_last=False),
                num_workers=self.hparams.num_data_workers,
            )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `get_batch` instead of `__getitem__` and I don't see a point to do it like that.

[`torch.utils.data.BatchSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.BatchSampler) takes indices from your `Sampler()` instance (in this case `3` of them) and returns it as `list` so those can be used in your `MyDataset` `__getitem__` method (check [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#BatchSampler), most of samplers and data-related utilities are easy to follow in case you need it).

I assume your `self.ddf` supports list slicing (e.g. `self.ddf[[25, 44, 115]]` returns values correctly and uses only one expensive call). In this case simply switch `get_batch` into `__getitem__` and you are good to go.

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, remote_ddf, ):
        self.ddf = remote_ddf

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.ddf)

    def __getitem__(self, batch_idx):
        return self.ddf[batch_idx] -> batch_idx is a list
```

**EDIT:** You have to specify `batch_sampler` as `sampler`, otherwise the batch will be divided into single indices. This should be fine:

```
loader = DataLoader(
    dataset=dataset,
    # This line below!
    batch_sampler=BatchSampler(
        SequentialSampler(dataset), batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size, drop_last=False
    ),
    num_workers=self.hparams.num_data_workers,
)
```

Comment: Funny as it sounds, I couldn't understand it from the documentation. _getitem_ of a dataset sounds like something that returns one sample, in my case a row.

Comment: `torch.utils.data.Dataset` is a rather flexible structure (at least from pytorch version `1.4` IIRC) so `index` can be anything really AFAIK. If you use `batch_sampler` it is responsible for creating whole batch of data.

Comment: Of course, but from the documentation perspective, the collate function(aggregation) is done implicitly for you, meaning _get_ gets k times 1, and then aggregated. This means that *no* aggregation is being done after __getitem__

Comment: `collate_fn` allows you to "post-process" data after it's been returned from batch.  You may return `list[Tensor]` from your Dataset or get `list[Tensor]` gets returned when using standard sampler and you can create tensor from it. Good use case is padding for variable length tensors to be used with RNN or a-like. Though I agree `DataLoader` might be a little confusing.

Comment: Are you sure this is working for you? Updated my example with code as you advised

Comment: Yes hahaha! I just understood it now, and came to answer myself.
Thank you!